# RWeka in Windows 64 installed and can't load library

Tags: rstudio, rweka

I've successfully installed RWeka as shown below but when loading the library I get the error `there is no package called ‘RWeka’`

```
package ‘RWekajars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library\file1b2069d9552\RWeka’ to ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\library\RWeka’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\agarciar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY7D2K9\downloaded_packages
> library(RWeka)
Error in library(RWeka) : there is no package called ‘RWeka’
> Sys.getenv("R_ARCH") 
[1] "/x64"
> system("java -version")
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Both Java version and RStudio are in 64bits as also shown, I don't know what else to check